# OBIEE Agent to send mail doesn't mail

Tags: smtp, obiee

I am trying to set up via an OBIEE agent. I did the configuration of the smtp server in the EM and tested it via telnet. So this should be okay, but if I am running my agent I get this:

> Eventually succeeded, but encountered and resolved errors... 
>   Number of skipped deliveries: 2 of 3 
>   AgentID: /users/weblogic/testagent
>   [nQSError: 75027] Failed to open connection to SMTP Server (host localhost; port 25).

It says 'localhost' and I don't get why it doesn't connect to my mailserver. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

My instanceconfig.xml:

```
    <Alerts>
        <ScheduleServer ssl="false">localhost:9705</ScheduleServer>
        <OfflinePresentationServicesURL>http://10.232.18.95:9704/analytics/saw.dll</OfflinePresentationServicesURL>
    </Alerts>
    <ActionFramework>
        <WorkflowServer>http://10.232.18.95:9704</WorkflowServer>
        <WorkflowService>ANALYTICS</WorkflowService>
        <WorkflowSystem>obiaftests</WorkflowSystem>
    </ActionFramework>
```

My schedulerconfig.xml:

```
    <From>Oracle Delivers</From>
        <SMTP_Port>25</SMTP_Port>
        <SMTP_Server>localhost</SMTP_Server>
        <Sender>no-reply@oracle.com</Sender>
```

Comment: What version of OBIEE? It's evidently not using the config that you think you created. Can you post the relevant section of your `instanceconfig.xml` (from the scheduler's config folder, not sawserver)?

Comment: This is my OBIEE version: 12.2.1.1.0 (Build BIPS-20160604082456 64-bit). I've updated the part of instanceconfig above (is this the relevant part?)
Thanks!

Comment: Okay I understand it now! It's called schedulerconfig.xml and I didn't edit this. After editing this to the server, it worked so thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps in doing this:

1. configuring the SMTP server in Oracle EM
2. creating an agent in OBIEE
3. amending the `schedulerconfig.xml` file (located at OBI_HOME/user_projects/domains/bi/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/OBISCH)

I didn't do step 3 so OBIEE was trying to send over localhost. You should put the same server in here as configured in the EM.